# How to add a crust of crystals to this object?

Tags: particles, geometry

I have a heart object:

[image: heart]

I want to add crystals growing out of it (see image below for example of what I want)

[image: crystals growing]

So far, I've been manually adding crystal objects one by one, but I want to also be able to create a "skin" of crystal crust on certain faces, so that I can easily cover swathes of the heart in a fine scattering of crystals.

Should I use a particle system? Is there some way I can "spraypaint" crystal dust (not just texture, but actual crystal geometry) onto the model?

The heart will be animated, if it matters.

Comment: Particles seem a reasonable way to proceed.  Texture can drive particle size dynamically.  Texture can drive density/location a single frame.  You can resuse the crystals you already made if you put them in a group.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Particle system.

1. Model the crystals, i would recomend 5-6 different variations
2. Make them a group/collection(2.8)
3. Create a particle system.
4. Change the Render from eg. Halo to "Collection"
5. select your collection with the models
6. add a VertexWeigth in the Vertex settings as ammount
7. go to weigth paint and paint on where you need them to be.

You can also create a weigth paint for size to controll it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/75406)

Comment: I flagged this, since it doesn't elaborate on the "***How*** to add a crust".

Comment: I edited it to to fit the question better. Thank you for pointing out my mistakes! :)

Comment: This is much better, have an upvote.